# Code run in a weird way in Visual Studio code (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm wryting some code in VSC in python, and I've noticed a weird behavior:

```
mio_dict = {"Chiave1": "valore1", "Chiave2": "valore2", 29: 4}

mio_dict.get(4, "key not found")
mio_dict.get(29, "key not found")
```

Basically, if I've only mio_dict.get(4, "chiave non trovata"), it replies correctly,
but if I`ve both as in the block, it replies only with the second result, as the first isn't there...any ideas why?

Similarly, in the terminal sometimes it doesn't work at all, but in the interactive shell yes...why???

Thank you

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking, but 4 isn't a key in that dictionary. It's a value paired with the key 29.

Comment: are you using Jupiter notebook? if so it displays only the last display output. use print. `print(mio_dict.get(4, "key not found"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is somewhat vague. First, please clarify the definition of **[dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)**， which is a one-to-one correspondence between key and value.

In your case, 29 is **key** and 4 is **value**.

Let's read the definition of `get(key[,default])` method:

Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to `None`, so that this method never raises a KeyError.

In your codes,

```
mio_dict.get(4, "key not found")
mio_dict.get(29, "key not found")
```

The first will return "key not found" because 4 is not a key in the dictionary `mio_dict`, the second will return 4 because 29 is a key and it's value is 4.

You can use debug to see the value that these two lines return or you can use method print() to see the output.

```
print(mio_dict.get(4, "key not found"))
print(mio_dict.get(29, "key not found"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you all for the answer. I'm sorry I didn't explained what is a dictionary but, if so, I didn't also explained what's a variable and so on, because it's part of the language. Said so, yeah with print it works thanks.